# How to send locust metrics to prometheus using locust exporter?

Tags: python, prometheus, locust

I came accross [locust exporter](https://github.com/mbolek/locust_exporter). So I installed it and followed the steps and as said in document I ran the commmand locust_exporter.py 1234 localhost:8089 where 1234 is a port. But it throwing some error.

> Exception happened during processing of request from ('127.0.0.1',
>   11950) Traceback (most recent call last):   File
>   "E:\Python\lib\socketserver.py", line 650, in process_request_thread
>       self.finish_request(request, client_address)   File "E:\Python\lib\socketserver.py", line 360, in finish_request
>       self.RequestHandlerClass(request, client_address, self)   File "E:\Python\lib\socketserver.py", line 720, in **init**
>       self.handle()   File "E:\Python\lib\http\server.py", line 426, in handle
>       self.handle_one_request()   File "E:\Python\lib\http\server.py", line 414, in handle_one_request
>       method()   File "E:\Python\lib\site-packages\prometheus_client\exposition.py", line
>   152, in do_GET
>       output = encoder(registry)   File "E:\Python\lib\site-packages\prometheus_client\exposition.py", line
>   121, in generate_latest
>       output.append(sample_line(s))   File "E:\Python\lib\site-packages\prometheus_client\exposition.py", line
>   77, in sample_line
>       ['{0}="{1}"'.format(   File "E:\Python\lib\site-packages\prometheus_client\exposition.py", line
>   78, in 
>       k, v.replace('\', r'\').replace('\n', r'\n').replace('"', r'\"')) AttributeError: ("'NoneType' object has no attribute
>   'replace'", Metric(locust_requests_avg_content_ length, Locust
>   requests avg_content_length, gauge, ,
>   [Sample(name='locust_requests_avg_content_lengt h', labels={'path':
>   '/charts.html', 'method': 'GET'}, value=19561.0, timestamp=None,
>   exemplar=None),  Sample(name='locust_requests_avg_content_length',
>   labels={'path': '/index.html', 'method': 'GET'}, value=31333.0,
>   timestamp=None, exemplar=None),
>   Sample(name='locust_requests_avg_content_length', lab els={'path':
>   'Aggregated', 'method': None}, value=25447.0, timestamp=None,
>   exemplar=None)]))
>
> Exception happened during processing of request from ('127.0.0.1',
>   11951) Traceback (most recent call last):   File
>   "E:\Python\lib\socketserver.py", line 650, in process_request_thread
>       self.finish_request(request, client_address)   File "E:\Python\lib\socketserver.py", line 360, in finish_request
>       self.RequestHandlerClass(request, client_address, self)   File "E:\Python\lib\socketserver.py", line 720, in **init**
>       self.handle()   File "E:\Python\lib\http\server.py", line 426, in handle
>       self.handle_one_request()   File "E:\Python\lib\http\server.py", line 414, in handle_one_request
>       method()   File "E:\Python\lib\site-packages\prometheus_client\exposition.py", line
>   152, in do_GET
>       output = encoder(registry)   File "E:\Python\lib\site-packages\prometheus_client\exposition.py", line
>   121, in generate_latest
>       output.append(sample_line(s))   File "E:\Python\lib\site-packages\prometheus_client\exposition.py", line
>   77, in sample_line
>       ['{0}="{1}"'.format(   File "E:\Python\lib\site-packages\prometheus_client\exposition.py", line
>   78, in 
>       k, v.replace('\', r'\').replace('\n', r'\n').replace('"', r'\"')) AttributeError: ("'NoneType' object has no attribute
>   'replace'", Metric(locust_requests_avg_content_ length, Locust
>   requests avg_content_length, gauge, ,
>   [Sample(name='locust_requests_avg_content_lengt h', labels={'path':
>   '/charts.html', 'method': 'GET'}, value=19561.0, timestamp=None,
>   exemplar=None),  Sample(name='locust_requests_avg_content_length',
>   labels={'path': '/index.html', 'method': 'GET'}, value=31333.0,
>   timestamp=None, exemplar=None),
>   Sample(name='locust_requests_avg_content_length', lab els={'path':
>   'Aggregated', 'method': None}, value=25447.0, timestamp=None,
>   exemplar=None)])

Not sure what the error is all about.How to resolve this?

Answer (score 1):

You can try  to use this exporter: [ContainerSolutions/locust_exporter](https://github.com/ContainerSolutions/locust_exporter)

```
docker run --net=host containersol/locust_exporter
```

by default it will try to connect to locust on http://localhost:8089
and metrics will be exposed on http://localhost:9646/metrics

I wrote a blog post about [How to Move Metrics from Locust.io to Grafana via Prometheus](https://pperzyna.com/blog/how-to-move-metrics-from-locust_io-to-grafana-via-prometheus/).